# What are differences between traditional whisked whipped cream and whipping syphon?

Tags: whipped-cream

Is there any perceived taste or texture difference between traditional whisked whipped cream and whipping syphon.  Assuming, for comparison, identical mix of cream and a little sugar.
Also, if say lemon juice, liqueur, or other flavourings are included does the N2O react with those in any way?

[edited for typo]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you whip cream with a wisk, you can easily control the texture/consistency on a fairly fine scale, from liquid to butter.  With a whipper you have, essentially, one output, similar to the consistency of whipped cream that you can purchase in a can, ready to dispense.  Taste variation is influenced by other variables (raw product, flavorings). N2O does not interact with other flavorings, but they can easily be added to a whipper.  The only concern is anything solid that might get caught in the seal of the whipper.  Something as small as ground pepper could cause a problem here.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the texture is certainly different. Hand-whipped and mixer-whipped cream is denser and fattier, while pressure-whipped cream is lighter and liquid-ier. Also, pressure-whipped cream loses its shape quite soon after being expressed, while hand-whipped stands firm for quite a while after whipping.

Moscafj had the right keyword: cans of whipped cream are simply dispensable versons of permanent syphons. So you can buy one of those, then whip by hand, and compare the results side-by-side.

The taste is not changed, with or without flavorings. Although there are not many flavorings that you can add to cream without preventing it from foaming.